# Find the line number containing a given span

Tags: python, file, indices

Given a text file, how would one find the line number corresponding to given start and end indices for a substring? Even though the value of any given span can be found, the data set I'm working with contains duplicates.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, and offer a sample input and what you expect to see. Also, please explain what you have done so far.

Comment: I have a text file that contains the phrase "Amphotericin B" between characters 1673 and 1687. I need a function that, given the text of the file and the start and end indices, returns the line number of that exact instance of the phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line_number = my_string[:start_index].count("\n")`

I guess ...

```
my_string = """
hello
test
line 
numbers
"""

print(my_string[:14].count("\n")) # the 14th character is the 3rd line
```